Reference Request for Worksheets for Logic
I wanted to ask, could someone point me to a resource that gives problems to analyze and use logic to detect arguments, fallacies, etc. (problems like those in Copi's Intro to Logic) with an answer key? It would help to have a summation of various important ideas in logic and fallacy.

Maybe useful P.Smith's Introduction as well as Sets Logic Computation. An Open Introduction to Metalogic (2021)

Copi's book is horrible; it is full of terrible explanations that only create confusion and conceptual misunderstandings. If you want to learn proper logical reasoning, let me know.
